# Issue pulling data from the firebase realtime database with child_added in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having trouble retrieving posts from the firebase realtime database with javascript:

```
var postsRef = database.ref().child('posts');
postsRef.on('child_added', postData => {
    console.log(postData.val().title, postData.val().content, 
    postData.val().author);
    addPostElement(postData.val().title, postData.val().content, postData.val().author);
});
```

That is exactly what is said in the documentation, but it never runs, even though (the `child_added` event) should be triggered once for every post

Answer (score 0):

try setting postsRef to database.ref('posts') also cloud functions has a cleaner api for listening to this type of events its worth giving it a look

Comment: Still never called :\